ROS2 remote compile with VS2022
My target system is a remote machine ROS2 Galactic on Ubuntu 20.04.6 TLS and my other PC Windows 10 and Visual Studio 2022.
Connection is set up and also CMakePresets.json and it almost works. Can copy files to the remote machine and compile with Colcon from there. It does not work from VS directly.
Ok, not true, I had it working once before but can't remember how I fixed it, so in general it is possible.
I didn't mess with the Linux and ROS system, so it must be a VS setting which got lost.
here some config files and hope they are helpful to localize the problem.
the part in CMakePresets.json
    {
      "name": "ubuntu-ros2-galactic-debug",
      "displayName": "Ubuntu ROS 2 Galactic Debug",
      "generator": "Ninja",
      "binaryDir": "${sourceDir}/out/build/${presetName}",
      "installDir": "${sourceDir}/out/install/${presetName}",
      "cacheVariables": {
        "CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE": "Debug",
        "CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH": "/opt/ros/galactic",
        "CMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS": "YES"
      },
      "condition": {
        "type": "equals",
        "lhs": "${hostSystemName}",
        "rhs": "Linux"
      },
      "vendor": {
        "microsoft.com/VisualStudioRemoteSettings/CMake/1.0": {
          "sourceDir": "$env{HOME}/src/mb_ws/src/mb/$ms{projectDirName}"
        }
      }
    }

CMakeLists.txt in root directory
# CMakeList.txt : Top-level CMake project file, do global configuration
# and include sub-projects here.

cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 3.8)

# Enable Hot Reload for MSVC compilers if supported.
if (POLICY CMP0141)
  cmake_policy(SET CMP0141 NEW)
  set(CMAKE_MSVC_DEBUG_INFORMATION_FORMAT "$<IF:$<AND:$<C_COMPILER_ID:MSVC>,$<CXX_COMPILER_ID:MSVC>>,$<$<CONFIG:Debug,RelWithDebInfo>:EditAndContinue>,$<$<CONFIG:Debug,RelWithDebInfo>:ProgramDatabase>>")
endif()

if(CMAKE_COMPILER_IS_GNUCXX OR CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_ID MATCHES "Clang")
  add_compile_options(-Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic)
endif()

set(PYTHON_EXECUTABLE /usr/bin/python3)

project ("position_estimate")

# find dependencies
find_package(ament_cmake REQUIRED)
find_package(geometry_msgs REQUIRED)
find_package(rclcpp REQUIRED)
find_package(tf2 REQUIRED)
find_package(tf2_ros REQUIRED)
find_package(turtlesim REQUIRED)

and the error in VS
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State   Details
Error       CMake Error at /opt/ros/galactic/share/ament_cmake_core/cmake/ament_cmake_package_templates-extras.cmake:41 (message):
  execute_process(/usr/bin/python3
  /opt/ros/galactic/share/ament_cmake_core/cmake/package_templates/templates_2_cmake.py
  /home/michael/src/mb_ws/src/mb/position_estimate/out/build/ubuntu-ros2-galactic-debug/ament_cmake_package_templates/templates.cmake)
  returned error code 1     /opt/ros/galactic/share/ament_cmake_core/cmake/ament_cmake_package_templates-extras.cmake           


VS compiler output
1> Copying files to the remote machine.
1> Starting copying files to remote machine.
1> Finished copying files (elapsed time 00h:00m:00s:588ms).
1> CMake generation started for configuration: 'ubuntu-ros2-galactic-debug'.
1> Found cmake executable at /usr/bin/cmake.
1> /usr/bin/cmake -G "Ninja"   -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE:STRING="Debug" -DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH:STRING="/opt/ros/galactic" -DCMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS:STRING="YES" -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX:PATH="/home/michael/src/mb_ws/src/mb/position_estimate/out/install/ubuntu-ros2-galactic-debug"   /home/michael/src/mb_ws/src/mb/position_estimate/CMakeLists.txt;
1> [CMake] -- Found ament_cmake: 1.1.6 (/opt/ros/galactic/share/ament_cmake/cmake)
1> [CMake] -- Using PYTHON_EXECUTABLE: /usr/bin/python3
1> [CMake] Traceback (most recent call last):
1> [CMake]   File "/opt/ros/galactic/share/ament_cmake_core/cmake/package_templates/templates_2_cmake.py", line 21, in <module>
1> [CMake]     from ament_package.templates import get_environment_hook_template_path
1> [CMake] ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'ament_package'
1> [CMake] CMake Error at /opt/ros/galactic/share/ament_cmake_core/cmake/ament_cmake_package_templates-extras.cmake:41 (message):
1> [CMake]   execute_process(/usr/bin/python3
1> [CMake]   /opt/ros/galactic/share/ament_cmake_core/cmake/package_templates/templates_2_cmake.py
1> [CMake]   /home/michael/src/mb_ws/src/mb/position_estimate/out/build/ubuntu-ros2-galactic-debug/ament_cmake_package_templates/templates.cmake)
1> [CMake]   returned error code 1
1> [CMake] Call Stack (most recent call first):
1> [CMake]   /opt/ros/galactic/share/ament_cmake_core/cmake/ament_cmake_coreConfig.cmake:41 (include)
1> [CMake]   /opt/ros/galactic/share/ament_cmake/cmake/ament_cmake_export_dependencies-extras.cmake:15 (find_package)
1> [CMake]   /opt/ros/galactic/share/ament_cmake/cmake/ament_cmakeConfig.cmake:41 (include)
1> [CMake]   CMakeLists.txt:21 (find_package)
1> [CMake] -- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
1> [CMake] See also "/home/michael/src/mb_ws/src/mb/position_estimate/out/build/ubuntu-ros2-galactic-debug/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
1> cd "/home/michael/src/mb_ws/src/mb/position_estimate/out/build/ubuntu-ros2-galactic-debug";/usr/bin/cmake -G "Ninja"   -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE:STRING="Debug" -DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH:STRING="/opt/ros/galactic" -DCMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS:STRING="YES" -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX:PATH="/home/michael/src/mb_ws/src/mb/position_estimate/out/install/ubuntu-ros2-galactic-debug"   /home/michael/src/mb_ws/src/mb/position_estimate 2>&1; returned with exit code: 1


seems it can't find find_package(ament_cmake REQUIRED)
and if I comment it out it complains about find_package(geometry_msgs REQUIRED) and so on.
But it cannot be the problem because it works with Colcon on the other machine.
Any ideas?
